# Error installing a django project AttrributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator'

Tags: python, django

i am trying to use this project https://github.com/tangjon/Build-a-PC-Configuration-Tool but i have an error in the process. First of all i am cloning the project using this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/tangjon/Build-a-PC-Configuration-Tool.git
```

after that i am changing directory and go to:

```
cd Build-a-PC-Configuration-Tool
```

installing the requirements:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

change directory again to go into the manage.py for migrations:

```
cd bapccanada
```

then migrate:

```
python manage.py make migrations
```

and here is the error **AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator'**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR0Nl.png)

Any ideas to solve the error? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The version of Django in that project is not compatible with Python 3.10.

You'll need to either

- use an older version of Python (Django 2.x, as used by that project supports up to Python 3.7)
- or **preferably** do the work to make the project compatible with a newer version of Django. At the time of writing, Django 4.0 was just released a few days ago. You can then contribute those changes back to the project as a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

If you have This type of Error:-

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator' (Django)

then you can solve it easily by this method.

Solution:-

```
   1. press **(win+r)/(mac+r)** and type cmd then enter.
   2. Type in cmd, **pip uninstall django**. (This method doesn't affect your 
   project.
   3. Then again type **pip install django**
   4. Then run your project. **[py manage.py runserver][1]**
```

After all, the commands you see, your error is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that official deprecation warning (in Python pre 3.10) explains everything.

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Iterator
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead
of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
<class 'collections.abc.Iterator'>
```