# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm diving into a Django docs and I'm using the latest Django (4.0.4) and Python 3.10.0

Whenever I try the command `django-admin startproject mysite` it gives the error "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator'"

I am using a virtual environment as well which has the Django installed on it.
I tried uninstalling the django and reinstalling but no changed in the program..

Please guide me into the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70347099/error-installing-a-django-project-attrributeerror-module-collections-has-no-a

Comment: What do you mean by “full stack trace”?

Answer (score 0):

Django 4.0.4 was just released few days back.
You know, django-admin is a Python script that gets added to your [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) so that it's invocable from the command line with django-admin (as opposed to something like python3 -m django_admin) maybe there was an older version lurking around your PATH that reinstalling will help you fix

or

Use an older version of Python (Django 2.x, as used by that project supports up to Python 3.7).